# How to design and write a game efficiently?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm writing a very simple Java Game. Let me describe it briefly:

- There are 4 players in a Map.
- The map is a two-dimensional matrix with a value called "height"
- The height between 2 nodes is the cost of that edge.
- Use Dijkstra algorithm to help player navigate from a source to a destination.
- Four players take turn to make a move. The total move is 8( left top, top, right top.... )
- If they meets, fight for gold value, otherwise move to their target.
- As they move, their strength decrease by the height difference between two nodes.
- ... etc

....
The problem that I'm encountering is that the source code is getting longer and complex day by day. And I think I'm using a wrong approach somehow, I feel so tired because of constantly changing the implementation. Here is my approach:

1. Write out all requirements.
2. Create all the object that I need with all getter and setter.
3. Create a static class to test the logic
4. Create unit test while putting the logic together
5. Add some more code, then change to code to fit the test
6. Write a big method that run, then break it down into smaller methods, then write unit test again.
7. If everything work fine, add more requirements, add more code
8. Then things are getting complicated because the more code I added, the complexity increases. No longer have time to write unit test because create a test case now requires too much work
9. Re-design, then change the implementation, go to step 1 again.

I'm come from a C++ background, and I'm only comfortable with writing 'static' libraries such as: stack, queue, link-listed, tree... Game is really a big challenging to me, especially I have to use Java. I understand the core programming is the same, so picking up Java was not really that bad. However, the time of looking up Java's API is not little. Further, the game logic is really hard to write. When this object moves, other object got affected..., so creating test for a method depends on many other methods...etc. 
I really need an advice. Could anyone share some experience of how to write a game to me? I only have two weeks left for this assignment. I'm currently have 45 classes now, I feel so lost because the more I wrote the more it gets complex :( !

Best regards,
Chan Nguyen

Comment: This may be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start thinking like a java programmer. Think as every thing in your game as an object, like the board, think about the properties and methods it has, its interfaces, how it interacts with the other objects.
If you need help getting started here is a great tutorial that guides you step by step to do a simple java game, this might put you in the right frame of mind to start programming your own. I strongly recommend you to follow the tutorial.http://www.cokeandcode.com/asteroidstutorial and to use the libraries that they used for developing the interfaz there.

Comment: @Soffer: thanks for your suggestion. I think I should read some books in game programming first.

Answer (score 0):

I view game code architects with respect: games are complex systems with emergent properties at runtime, unusually intense interaction requirements (UI, controls) which makes a lot of OOP theory questionable value.  It can be difficult to reuse game code. And, a lot of upfront planning work is wasted time.

Most game coders I know, beginning or veteran, succeed with a "just do it"  iterative process. e.g.

1) write a minimal prototype. get a very basic system working, using the simplest, most obvious architecture you can think of.  (my guy can run around the screen). 5 or 10 objects max.

2) add functionality (points, rules, traps, NPC behaviours, etc) and playtest, over and over.  This hack on hack can makes for poorly structured code, but most coders can make it work.

3) rewrite. Programmers grit their teeth at some of the hacking they had to do in (2), and will want to throw it all out and rewrite.  Resist this urge until the game is testable (as in, plyaers can sometimes enjoy it, somewhat), or a new feature would require rewriting. Then, rewrite pretty much EVERYTHING from scratch.  This goes WAY faster than you'd expect, and results in solid, well-structured code.

Game coders do test, but comprehensive testing of ALL code is rare. two reasons: emergence and culture.  Games have emergent properties at runtime ("yeah, but the points COULD go negative when the NPC is killed when ....").  Since games are usually for entertainment purposes, there is a culture of fast-and-loose testing.  Games aren't as important as, say, missile control code.

I expect others with more coding experience answer this. (I have written a fair bit of code but I tend toward quick and dirty script type coding style - I know lots of coders who are way better than me.)